# Splitting string by combining character groups

Tags: excel, vba, unicode

I’m using Excel vba to process strings that contain Unicode combining characters. I need to split the string into an array of characters... easy enough. The problem I have is that I need character groups. That is, characters with their combining characters. How do you split a string into groups of character + combining characters using Excel vba?

Comment: Regex I am guessing if it is pattern matching... It would be more useful if you posted an example string and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

VBA has no direct function to deal with combined chars as you wish. Instead, you will have to work your way around with some code. As of matter of fact, it is not a VBA specific problem, read https://eev.ee/blog/2015/09/12/dark-corners-of-unicode/#combining-characters-and-character-width.

The following code will attempt to handle the most common combined chars problems and has to do with diacritical marks (variable `unicode()` will store the splitted unicode string you need)

Of course, combined chars may extend away from marks, like ae as an unique letter or ß which can also be written as ss.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    
    ' Set some combined chars in A1 cell
    r = "a" + ChrW(&H300)
    r = r + "e" + ChrW(&H301)
    r = r + "i" + ChrW(&H305)
    r = r + "o" + ChrW(&H300)
    r = r + "u" + ChrW(&H300)
    

    ' Store the combined chars from cell A1 to str
    Dim str As String
    str = r
    ' Length, counting the individual characters in string
    Dim strLen As Integer
    strLen = Len(str)
    
    
    ' Each element in unicode() will contain combined chars
    Dim unicode() As String
    ReDim unicode(strLen)
    
    ' Length, counting the combined characters in string
    Dim unicodeLength As Integer
    unicodeLength = 0
    
    
    ' Split str into unicode()
    Dim char As Integer
    For i = 1 To strLen
        char = AscW(Mid(str, i, 1))
        
        unicode(unicodeLength) = unicode(unicodeLength) + ChrW(char)
        
        If i < strLen Then
            'If it is not the last char, check if
            'the following char is a combining diacritical mark
            'and if so, do not increment the length
            char = AscW(Mid(str, i + 1, 1))
            If Not (char >= &H300 And char <= &H36F) Then
                unicodeLength = unicodeLength + 1
            End If
        Else
            unicodeLength = unicodeLength + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    
    ' Fill B column with 1 combined char per row
    For i = 1 To unicodeLength
        ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i) = unicode(i - 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

This code doesn't consider three main things:

1. There are more (rare) unicode characters besides (U+0300 to U+036F)
2. Some diacritical marks (like those from U+035C to U+0362) link two characters together, i.e. a͜b `"a" + ChrW(&H35C) + "b"`. In which case you will have to write some additional conditions.
3. If there are some diacritical marks, there will be empty spaces in `unicode()` array. In which case you will have to `ReDim Preserve` with the `unicodeLength` to free some space, or use `unicodeLength` as your upper bound.

For more information
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks

> Combining Diacritical Marks (0300–036F), since version 1.0, with
> modifications in subsequent versions down to 4.1
>
> Combining Diacritical Marks Extended (1AB0–1AFF), version 7.0
>
> Combining Diacritical Marks Supplement (1DC0–1DFF), versions 4.1 to 5.2
>
> Combining Diacritical Marks for Symbols (20D0–20FF), since version 1.0, with modifications
> in subsequent versions down to 5.1
>
> Combining Half Marks (FE20–FE2F), versions 1.0, with modifications in subsequent versions down to 8.0

Comment: Doesn’t answer my question... That loops through each character. Combining characters are treated separately. I need combining characters to be grouped together in my loop.